# Turning on laptop on a specific time?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, power-management, 64-bit

I have Win7 x64 on my Sony AR-890U laptop.
Is it possible to turn on my laptop on a specific time ?

BTW, I'm not at home for some days and I'm gonna turn on and turn off my laptop repeatedly in these days.

Comment: Would this laptop support Wake on Lan?

Comment: @lvo Flipse: I don't know? How should I find it?

Comment: If you boot up the laptop, enter the bios settings and have a look around. I'm trying to find the manual and hope that I can see what options you have. Though ChrisF's solution should work just fine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a scheduled task then there is an option on the Settings tab (at least it's on the settings tab in XP) that states:

> Wake the computer to run this task.

This should wake the computer "even if the computer is in Sleep mode and uses OnNow power management".

All you need is to choose/create a simple task to run.

Obviously the machine needs to have power (which a laptop should have).

Comment: In Win7 I could find `Wake the computer to run this task` on Conditions tab.

Comment: @Mohammad - I don't have Windows 7 to hand so I couldn't double check where it's moved to.

Answer (score 2):

Some computers allow to wake-up by an alarm through their bios:

- Go to your bios settings (press Del when your PC is loading).
- Go to “Power Management Setup” and enable “PWron/Resume by alarm” and set date alarm and time alarm and then press F10 to save your change and turn off your pc.

On the specified date and time, your pc will turn on

Comment: I have also seen this option in many PC BIOSes, though I have never personally used it or seen it in action.